# How to open or close a Modal defined in one Class from a Button defined in another Class

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, bootstrap-modal, react-bootstrap

I'm writing a simple webapp with React and react-bootstrap. I have two Buttons that should open two different Modals. I want to separate the Class containing the Buttons from the two Modal Classes, e.g.

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');

import { Button, Modal, closeButton } from 'react-bootstrap';

var Jumbo = React.createClass ({
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <Button onClick={Modal1.open}>Modal1</Button>
        <Button onClick={Modal2.open}>Modal2</Button>
        <Modal1 />
        <Modal2 />
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var Modal1 = React.createClass ({
  getInitialState() {
    return {
      showModal: false
    };
  },

  close() {
    this.setState({
      showModal: false
    });
  },

  open() {
    this.setState({
      showModal: true
    });
  },

  render() {
    return (
      <Modal show={this.state.showModal} onHide={this.close}>
        <Modal.Header closeButton>
          <Modal.Title>Modal1</Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body>
          <p>Modal1</p>
        </Modal.Body>
        <Modal.Footer>
          <Button onClick={this.close}>Close</Button>
        </Modal.Footer>
      </Modal>
    );
  }
});

var Modal2 = React.createClass ({
  getInitialState() {
    return {
      showModal: false
    };
  },

  close() {
    this.setState({
      showModal: false
    });
  },

  open() {
    this.setState({
      showModal: true
    });
  },

  render() {
    return (
      <Modal show={this.state.showModal} onHide={this.close}>
        <Modal.Header closeButton>
          <Modal.Title>Modal2</Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body>
          <p>Modal2</p>
        </Modal.Body>
        <Modal.Footer>
          <Button onClick={this.close}>Close</Button>
        </Modal.Footer>
      </Modal>
    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(<Jumbo />, document.getElementById('modal'));
```

But `onClick={ModalN.open}` doesn't work. Normally I'd put the Button inside the Modal Class (as per [the documented example](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#modals-live)) and do `onClick={this.open}`, but I want to put the two Button elements together, not in separate `<div>`s. What's the correct way to pass in the reference to the Modal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onClick={modalN.open}` wont work, you need to include the `ModalN` component in `Jumbo`:

```
var Jumbo = React.createClass ({
  getInitialState() {
    return {
      activeModal: null
    }
  },

  openModal(id){
     this.setState({
        activeModal: id
     })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <Button onClick={this.openModal.bind(this,1)}>Modal1</Button>
        <Button onClick={this.openModal.bind(this,2)}>Modal2</Button>
        {this.state.activeModal === 1 ? <Modal1 /> :null}
        {this.state.activeModal === 2? <Modal2 /> : null}
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

You also need to change the intial `showModal` of each Modal to `true`, or else they won't ever show (since `open()` is never called):

```
var Modal1 = React.createClass ({
  getInitialState() {
    return {
      showModal: true
    }
  },
  ...
});
```

Comment: Thank you! There are some typos in your answer but this put me on the right track. For this to work with my code above, the `getInitialState()` function for each Modal needs to return `showModal: true`, or they are still hidden when the ternary operator activates the `<Modal />` element. I also had to add a `getInitialState()` to the `Jumbo` Class to set `activeModal: null` (or `0`, I don't think it matters) by default, to prevent an error.

Comment: Sorry to have accepted and then unaccepted this answer so quickly. I've discovered a bug - when I click the button to open `Modal1`, then close the Modal, I can't open `Modal1` again by pressing the same button. The only way to do it is to click the `Modal2` button, close it, and then click the `Modal1` button again. Is there a way to get around this?

Comment: I worked it out! From the [React discussion board](https://discuss.reactjs.org/t/is-this-a-decent-pattern-to-update-parent-state-from-children/560) I learned that you can pass in a function as a property from parent->child. Just add a `close()` method to `Jumbo` that sets `activeModal` to `null`, pass it in as `<ModalN close={this.close} />`, and then call it in the Modal Classes as `{this.props.close}` (e.g. `onHide=`, `onClick={this.props.close}`. You don't need to use the `getInitialState()`, `open()` and `close()` functions inside the Modal Class anymore. I edited the answer to reflect it.

Comment: yeah gr8 sorry i couldnt answer in time